# Force javaws to use Java 7 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I have Java 6, 7, and 8 installed on OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

I have a particular JNLP file that I need to launch with Java 7.

Choosing between 6 and 8 is easy. For 8 I just use "javaws" and for 6 I can use either

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javaws foo.jnlp
```

or

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 --exec javaws foo.jnlp
```

But this doesn't work for for Java 7:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7 --exec javaws foo.jnlp
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javaws" (-1)
```

Because there is no Home/bin/javaws for Java 7 and 8. There is only /usr/bin/javaws which links to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws and that only runs the most recent Java version.

So is there a way to launch a JNLP under Java 7 when you have Java 8 installed?
(I'll need to switch back and forth so "uninstall Java 8" is not a very good answer)

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the JNLP?  If so, `<java version="1.7"/>` would solve the problem.

Comment: No, I tried that already. It still runs in 1.8 despite the version String in the JNLP. I see this in the Java console: `Java Web Start 11.31.2.13
Using JRE version 1.8.0_31-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
`

Comment: To clarify my previous comment:

Editing the JNLP on the client side after download does nothing; looks like it checks with the server again to get the version when it launches.

If I change the version on the server side then I get this warning:  
"This application would like to use a version of Java (1.7) that is not installed on your system. ..."  
It then give me the choices of running on the latest version or cancelling. It does not give me the choice to run under 1.7.  

I do have both JDK 1.7 and 1.8 installed. But apparently only JRE 1.8, and the installer won't let me install JRE 1.7.